# Creating a program to integrate a function given by the user in C

Tags: c, integration, numerical-integration

I am trying to create a program to integrate a function given by the user in C, using various integration methods. I am able to program functions that I have put into the code body itself, but not one that is input by the user. Here is a program I have made for the midpoint rule, which integrates 1/(2+x^2):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<math.h>

#define f(x) 1/(2+pow(x,2))

int main()
{
 float lower, upper, integration=0.0, stepSize, n;
 int i, subInterval;
 /* Input */
 printf("Enter lower limit of integration: ");
 scanf("%f", &lower);
 printf("Enter upper limit of integration: ");
 scanf("%f", &upper);
 printf("Enter number of sub intervals: ");
 scanf("%d", &subInterval);

 stepSize = (upper - lower)/subInterval;

 integration = f(lower) + f(upper);
 for(i=1; i<= subInterval-1; i++)
    {
        k = lower + i*stepSize;
        integration = integration + 2 * f(n);
    }

 integration = integration * stepSize/2;
 printf("\nRequired value of integration is: %.5f", integration);
 getch();
 return 0;
}
```

Additionally, I have a separate program for the input of a function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAXSIZE 10

void main()
{
    int array[MAXSIZE];
    int i, num, power;
    float x, polySum;

    printf("Enter the order of the polynomial \n");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    /*  Read the coefficients into an array */
    printf("Enter %d coefficients \n", num + 1);
    for (i = 0; i <= num; i++)
        {
            scanf("%d", &array[i]);
        }
    polySum = array[0];
    for (i = 1; i <= num; i++)
        {
            polySum = polySum * x + array[i];
        }
    power = num;

    printf("Given polynomial is: \n");

    for (i = 0; i <= num; i++)
        {
            if (power < 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        /*  printing proper polynomial function */
        if (array[i] > 0)
            printf(" + ");
        else if (array[i] < 0)
            printf(" - ");
        else
            printf(" ");
        printf("%dx^%d  ", abs(array[i]), power--);
    }
}
```

TLDR; I'm trying to find a way to combine the 2 pieces of code I have to perform integration of a user-input function.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!
This is a site for asking questions about technical issues that need a specific answer, not for having people write the code for you.
If you wrote the two programs you posted, you should be able to combine them yourself. If you have issues doing so, please first post what you did combining them and where is your struggle.

Comment: Convert each one to a function that takes appropriate arguments. Separate the computation from the input and the output.